# What type of keyboard is this?

Tags: keyboard

I have an old HP SK-2505 keyboard (as well as another very similar one by the same company). What type of keyboard is it? Membrane, dome-switch, scissor-switch, mechanical-switch, buckling-spring, etc.? There are many types, and I don't know how to identify the correct one just by looking.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I will remove some keys and take a photo when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

From the age and look of it, I'm guessing it's a rubber dome keyboard, though the only real way to find out for sure is to take the keyboard apart.

Comment: I will disassemble the keyboard and take another photo when I get the chance.

Comment: I added two more photos. There appear to be white plastic half-domes at the bottom of each key.

Comment: @posfan12: You're not deep enough yet. Keep disassembling.